# Is there a safe way to specify the value of an object may be uninitialized because it is never used?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, micro-optimization

Disclaimer: The following is a purely academic question; I keep this code at least 100 m away from any production system. The problem posed here is something that cannot be measured in any “real life” case.

Consider the following code ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/6cF7Bb)):

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (*func_t)(int *ptr); // functions must conform to this interface

extern int uses_the_ptr(int *ptr);
extern int doesnt_use_the_ptr(int *ptr);

int foo() {
    // actual selection is complex, there are multiple functions,
    // but I know `func` will point to a function that doesn't use the argument
    func_t func = doesnt_use_the_ptr;

    int *unused_ptr_arg = NULL; // I pay a zeroing (e.g. `xor reg reg`) in every compiler
    int *unused_ptr_arg; // UB, gcc zeroes (thanks for saving me from myself, gcc), clang doesn't
    int *unused_ptr_arg __attribute__((__unused__)); // Neither zeroing, nor UB, this is what I want

    return (*func)(unused_ptr_arg);
}
```

The compiler has no reasonable way to know that `unused_ptr_arg` is unneeded (and so the zeroing is wasted time), but I do, so I want to inform the compiler that `unused_ptr_arg` may have any value, such as whatever happens to be in the register that would be used for passing it to `func`.

Is there a way to do this? I know I’m way outside the standard, so I’ll be fine with compiler-specific extensions (especially for gcc & clang).

Comment: Compiler specific ways/extension exist for a need. Now, I don't doubt the validity of this question, but what need is there to conserve a single `xor reg reg`?

Comment: The `_MAGIC_COMPILER_UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` you need is the "standard" when you don't do any explicit initialization at all. If you want an uninitialized variable, then let it be uninitialized.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , leaving it uninitialized is UB, the risk of nasal demons is always present, you never know a "smart" optimizer might remove the function call entirely, it's UB

Comment: @StoryTeller , academical curiosity, as I wrote I'm absolutely not going to use this, but I was curious

Comment: Leaving a pointer uninitialized only leads to UB if the pointer is actually dereferenced. If you *know* it will never be dereferenced, there's no UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - There's a fine point here. If the pointer value is indeterminate, even copying its value is UB (assuming I'm not getting C and C++ mixed up here). So passing it to the function is itself UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller IIRC in C it's only UB if the value corresponds to a trap value. Which for any kind of integer values (which pointers really are on just about all systems) there really are none. In C++ it's specified that even reading an indeterminate value is UB (again IIRC).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - technically, accessing the VALUE of an uninitialised pointer gives undefined behaviour, which happens before dereferencing.    Practically, the consequences are only potentially observable with most implementations if the pointer is dereferenced.   For example, the act of passing an uninitialised pointer as an argument to a function does not, practically, cause unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I used a pointer because it has an obvious "default" value, but the unused variable could have been of any type.

Comment: `a "smart" optimizer might remove the function call entirely`.  Wrong: both functions are external, resolving their addresses is a task for the linker. Also: I do not see the problem of  *zeroing*. (performancewise: compared to a function call through a pointer it is nothing)

Comment: Would overriding the type work for you?  `typedef int (*func0_t)(void); return (*(func0_t)func)();` for paths of code that know `func == doesnt_use_the_ptr`

Comment: @chux I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @12345ieee All function pointers are cast-able to other function pointers.  With " know `func` will point to a function that doesn't use the argument", then cast `func` to a  function  pointer  that needs no arguments and then call that function.`(*(func0_t)func)()`.

Comment: You might consider rephrasing the question because what you require is actually a way to indicate to the compiler that the argument is unused or that you really do not care about the fact that `unused_ptr_arg` is uninitialized. For example, if `int *unused_ptr_arg = unused_ptr_arg;` were a valid way to express to the compiler that you did not care what value it had, that would be an acceptable solution, even though it does not use the “magic” value you request.

Comment: @chux: The fact that function pointers can be cast to other function pointers does not mean the pointed-to function may legally be called with the converted pointer. If the pointed-to function were defined to match, it would be okay, but then the caller has to know to do the cast, and that negates benefits of having a function pointer in the first place (being able to call the function via the pointer without knowing specifically which function is called).

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, you interpreted it correctly. Feel free to edit it for extra clarity, I couldn't figure a better way to express my intent.

Comment: @chux casting function ptrs is UB of the highest degree, you are messing with the calling convention. It'll probably work for this simple case, but not for more parameters.

Comment: @12345ieee "casting function ptrs is UB" is not so.  Casting is well defined.  "A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
type..."  C11 §6.3.2.3 8.  Calling casted function pointers may be an issue, but not the cast itself.

Comment: @12345ieee How about another approach: In addition to the [cast and call idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020196/is-there-a-safe-way-to-specify-the-value-of-an-object-may-be-uninitialized-becau/50020667#comment87058294_50020196), also make `int doesnt_use_the_ptr(int *ptr);` --> `int doesnt_use_the_ptr(void);` and change typedef to `typedef int (*func_t)();` which does not care about argument count/types?

Comment: @chux , the functions have to obey that interface for reason outside my immediate control (otherwise I would have obviously changed the signature)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Intel's SIMD intrinsics define do define something like a `_MAGIC_COMPILER_UNINITIALIZED_VALUE` for SIMD vector types:  [`__m128 v = _mm_undefined_ps();`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=undefined_&expand=5558)  which you might use as a destination for `movhlps`: https://godbolt.org/g/ucmHPN  gcc/clang typically just xor-zero a register, though; only ICC really does `movhlps` into a register with a (false) dependency on whatever the calling code was using it for.  Also interesting: `_mm256_castps128_ps256` leaves garbage in the high half.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using GCC/Clang `asm` Construct

In GCC and Clang, and other compilers that support GCC’s extended assembly syntax, you can do this:

```
int *unused_ptr_arg;
__asm__("" : "=x" (unused_ptr_arg));

return (*func)(unused_ptr_arg);
```

That `__asm__` construct [says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) “Here is some assembly code to insert into the program at this point. It writes a result to `unused_ptr_arg` in whatever location you choose for it.” (The `x` constraint means the compiler may choose memory, a processor register, or anything else the machine supports.) But the actual assembly code is empty (`""`). So no assembly code is generated, but the compiler believes that `unused_ptr_arg` has been initialized. In Clang 6.0.0 and GCC 7.3 (latest versions currently at Compiler Explorer) for x86-64, this generates a `jmp` with no `xor`.

## Using Standard C

Consider this:

```
int *unused_ptr_arg;
(void) &unused_ptr_arg;

return (*func)(unused_ptr_arg);
```

The purpose of `(void) &unused_ptr_arg;` is to take the address of `unused_ptr_arg`, even though the address is not used. This disables the rule in C 2011 [N1570] 6.3.2.1 2 that says behavior is undefined if a program uses the value of an uninitialized object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with `register`. Because its address is taken, it could not have been declared with `register`, and therefore using the value is no longer undefined behavior according to this rule.

In consequence, the object has an indeterminate value. Then there is an issue of whether pointers may have a trap representation. If pointers do not have trap representations in the C implementation being used, then no trap will occur due to merely referring to the value, as when passing it as an argument.

The [result with Clang 6.0.0 at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/oxYV89) is a `jmp` instruction with no setting of the parameter register, even if `-Wall -Werror` is added to the compiler options. In contrast, if the `(void)` line is removed, a compiler error results.

Comment: clang does what you say, but GCC complains

Comment: @12345ieee: In GCC, one can do `int *unused_ptr_arg = unused_ptr_arg;` to prevent it from warning about the lack of initialization (discovered by experiment, not compiler documentation). But that is unsatisfactory because GCC still generates the XOR, it is not valid C (uses an uninitialized value), and clang complains about it. I doubt you will find a single solution for all compilers, but you asked for compiler-specific solutions, so you may have to use preprocessor conditionals if you want to support multiple compilers.

Comment: Yes, I thank you very much for the clang code, I was already prepared to an `ifdef` wall. I thought that as you quoted the standard you were about to tell me how to make this work with gcc, but a clang solution mandated by the standard is already a big step ahead.

Comment: @12345ieee: I updated the answer with another solution.

Comment: It does work in any compiler! Amazing! Get +1 for now, I'll accept in a day if no "pure C" solution comes along.

Comment: You mask the UB and the warning by the cast. It is still the UB. This the abuse of the compiler which may lead to very well hided errors. IMO this an example what any coder should avoid. Passing the uninitialized pointer is always wrong, even if the function does not dereference it (so the question is why to pass it if it is not used).  This should be avoided as a plaque - and I see only one use in the function which will be implemented in the future to suppress the warning https://godbolt.org/g/j7zKyp

Comment: @PeterJ_01: The behavior is not undefined. It is defined by GCC and Clang. You can deal with plaque at the dentist.

Comment: @EricPostpischil of course - when the function called dereferences  the uninitialized pointer the behavior is defined by GCC and especially by Clang. LOL.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: A premise of the question is that the function does not dereference the pointer.

Comment: Great - so why to pass it at all. Any reason? Even as the academic question.  And the trivial example with no academic meaning. It is a classical example of the compiler abuse.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: As the question states, this is one particular case of a general situation in which all functions must conform to the type `int (*func_t)(int *ptr)`. Thus `func_t` is used to hold various pointers at various times. Some of the functions do use the parameter, and so a valid value needs to be passed. Some of the functions do not use the parameter, and no particular value needs to be passed. For performance, OP wants to avoid the unnecessary initialization when it is known the parameter will not be used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil there are the correct ways of archiving it without abusing the compiler. Same pointer and magically the calling function knows if it should initialize the variable. Hmm...... Any "academical" examples (of course with no (even a single instruction) code penalty)?

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Show a correct way of achieving the desired goal without abusing the compiler. As for the calling function knowing whether or not to initialize the object, there is no magic. It simply has some information about the function it is calling.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you give the example from my previous comment I will show you the correct way. Otherwise it is a complete waste of time as I cant think any example (except this kind useless, silly and trivial examples). Provide me the real example. And first show me how without the code penalty function will know if it should initialize the variable or not. You should have this example in your mind as you wrote that the single instruction was a huge performance penalty in your code. (IMO it was an imaginary code)

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I'm not sure why you are still discussing about this and wasting Eric's time. I read all the comments and he interpreted my question 100% correctly, and then gave a great answer, which works even when used in the real code (no, I'll not leave it there, but I wanted to test it).

Comment: I'll accept this now, to curb the useless discussion. As I used the 2nd code sample (the `__asm__` one), I ask you to please switch the order and put it first. Thanks again.

Comment: Would the "=r" constraint work when the calling convention uses the stack?  If not, would "=g" or "=rm" be better?

Comment: @technosaurus: `=r` will work because the compiler will honor it—it will choose a register, expect the assembly to put a value there, and will then use the value from there as it needs to (e.g., by moving it to the stack). However, `=rm` would be better, and so would `=x` (meaning any operand). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *unused_ptr_arg = NULL;
```

This is what you should be doing. You don't pay for anything. Zeroing an `int` is a no-op. Ok technically it's not, but practically it is. You will never ever ever see the time of this operation in your program. And I don't mean that it's so small that you won't notice it. I mean that it's so small that so many other factors and operations that are order of magnitude longer will "swallow" it.

Comment: I absolutely agree that this is what I *should* do (and in fact it's what I do in real code), this question was specifically asking for a method to forego the zeroing.

Comment: @12345ieee yes, but your problem is misleading. Just by asking this you validate the ideea that zeroing is taxing, even in a small amount. What I am trying to say is that the problem you are trying to solve (even academically) doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sure I can design a contrived example to measure the zeroing (like a function with 6+8 unused parameters), but I agree that I'm creating a problem that doesn't really exist in real life. I updated the disclaimer at the top.

Comment: This answer disputes the premises of the question and does not answer it. While one might argue that the cost of zeroing is trivial, that is based on assumptions about the machines used and the purposes and circumstances of the software. I have worked on extremely high performance code where the cost of zeroing or even no-op instructions was a factor, so it is reasonable to ask questions where the cost of zeroing is significant. This answer is bad because it fails to answer the question as asked. Disputes about the premises of a question belong in comments, not answers.

Comment: A `nop` instruction still isn't free.  On x86, xor-zeroing a register costs a 2-byte instruction.  It's the cheapest possible 2-byte instruction (on Sandybridge-family), but it still decodes to 1 uop that has to go through the pipeline, and takes space in the ROB until it retires.  (Not in the out-of-order scheduler, though, on CPUs which eliminate it in the issue/rename stage.  It enters the out-of-order part of the core in an already-executed state).  Related: [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44169342) nothing is free

Comment: Total uop throughput can easily be a bottleneck, and a zeroing instruction still costs an issue slot.  So does a `nop`; current x86 CPUs don't eliminate `nop`.  On AMD CPUs, `xor`-zeroing even uses an ALU uop, so it's not like a NOP.  See [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33666617)

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually possible across all architectures for a very good reason.

A call to a function may need to spill its arguments to the stack, and in IA64, spilling uninitialized registers to the stack can *crash* because the previous contents of the register was a speculative load that loaded an address that wasn't mapped.

Comment: This was addressed, essentially, in my answer. The IA64 NaT bits motivated the rule in c 2011 6.3.2.1 2 that using an uninitialized object can cause undefined behavior. However, as written in the standard, that rule applies only to objects that could have been declared `register`. By taking its address (so it cannot be `register`), we compel the compiler not to allow undefined behavior due to that rule. So a compiler for IA64 would have to avoid causing a trap due to that IA64 feature. But, with the same source code, compilers for other implementations could avoid initializing the object.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The value could still be a trap representation . We could say that any representation not corresponding to a mapped address is a trap representation

Comment: @M.M: That is also addressed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the possibility of zero-ing with each run of `int foo()`, simply make `unused_ptr_arg` `static`.

```
int foo() {
    func_t func = doesnt_use_the_ptr;
    static int *unused_ptr_arg;    
    return (*func)(unused_ptr_arg);
}
```

Comment: I've tested several compilers on godbolt, most keep the zeroing of the register, and some do a `mov` from static storage, which is even worse.

Comment: but it will zero it only on the startup which  is a completely different case.

Comment: @12345ieee "and some do a mov from static storage" --> I like to see this assembly code.  Certainty the _address_ of the `static unused_ptr_arg` is "moved".

Comment: @12345ieee you completely do not understand the topic. The adress of the function is know compile time and it actually is removed by the compiler as not needed. Declare the function pointer as volatile and you will see the difference. https://godbolt.org/g/YYDKMF

Comment: @PeterJ_01 declaring the function ptr as volatile only adds a ton of noise to the function call (as it should, the address has to be retrieved each time), but doesn't change at all the parameter zeroing strategy (you can check on godbolt). That's why I hardcoded it in.

Comment: the compiler knows that you do not change this function pointer in this function and it optimizes it out - which is 100% logical and expected.

Comment: @12345ieee here you fave no volatile example - but you must make it not calculable the compile time https://godbolt.org/g/bDJLwu

Comment: @PeterJ_01: sure, and if you add `static const` to that local array, ICC doesn't ridiculously copy it to the stack before indexing.  Then you can easily see that it still spends an instruction zeroing `rdi`, either xor-zero or a load from memory, just like this non-working answer, for gcc/clang/icc.  The OP is trying to eliminate *that* instruction and let the compiler leave whatever garbage is in RDI as the unused arg; optimizations on the function-pointer are orthogonal.

Comment: I know what OP wants. But the question why to pass the undefined variable to the function?